# Java InputStream.available() returning > 0 after reading

Tags: java, java-io, blocking, objectinputstream

I'm building a chat program where hosts are connected via sockets and talk to each other using ObjectInput and ObjectOutput streams. A host builds a string from keyboard input and sends it to the other hosts along with an array of ints.

After a host has successfully read a message via readObject(), the while(true) loop continues and that host hangs on the very next call of readObject(). I can only surmise that this is because indata.available() is returning true even after reading whatever was in it, and when it tries to read again before something else has been sent, it blocks (waits).

A snippet of the relevant code is below. I've done some research and found that I can't flush or empty an input stream. I also can't close it - because of the nature of the constantly-running chat program, it needs to stay open to continue reading.

Also, I understand that I'm checking indata.available() and then reading in using inputs.readObject(). I thought this was the proper way to do it, but correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm not sure what to do about it! I need indata.available() to return 0 if I haven't written an object to the stream.

```
    private InputStream[] indata;                
    private ObjectInputStream[] inputs;          
    private ObjectOutputStream[] outputs;        
    private int[] stamps;   

    // Establish connections via sockets between 3 hosts, serverless                     

    while (true) {
        // Build a message
        for (all hosts that aren't myself) {
            if ( i != rank ) {
                outputs[i].writeObject( message );
                outputs[i].writeObject( stamps );
                outputs[i].flush( ); 
                outputs[i].reset( );
            }
        }

        // Read a message in from a host that sent one
        for (all hosts that aren't myself) {
            if (indata[j].available() > 0) {
                String message = (String)inputs[j].readObject();
                int[] senderStamps = (int[])inputs[j].readObject();
            }
        }
    }
```

Some additional information, for clarification:

I'm using available() because the instructor used it in his code and I'm not allowed to change it. Further, the call to available() worked as intended when only one object (the string) was being sent - the only code that was there on the sending side was "writeObject" and "flush". It was my job to add the code to send the array, and when I do that, I also have to add the code to reset() the ObjectOutputStream (or I get other problems - when the array is sent, modified, and then sent again without calling reset() between sendings, the original, unmodified version is sent instead of the newly modified one).

I can't just block on read, as a process that's blocked on read cannot write to the other hosts, and I need to be able to write even when a host has nothing to read.

Also, we aren't allowed to use multiple threads.

Comment: `InputStream::available` always returns `0`. The javadocs of this method says that 'This method should be overridden by subclasses'. So can you post what a real implemented type of `indata`? Also, you read data from `inputs`. Can you post how `indata` and `inputs` are related?

Comment: I'm wondering if you can do a (str = inputs[j].readObject()) != null) as your check

Comment: @AnarAmrastanov It *is* overriden by subclasses, such as `ObjectInputStream`, which the OP is already using. Read the question.

Comment: The only problem here is the fact that you're using `available()` at all. Simple answer: don't. There are few if any correct uses of this method, and this isn't one of them. The fact that *some* bytes are available can never guarantee that an *entire object* is available, so you will *always* risk blocking in `readObject()`. So just do that. Block. Dedicate a thread to it, per socket.

Comment: @Benson99 No he can't. `readObject()` doesn't return `null` when an entire object isn't available. See the Javadoc.

Comment: NB 'I thought this was the proper way to do it': why? It isn't, and nowhere in the Javadoc or the Oracle Java Tutorial does it say otherwise.

Comment: @AnarAmrastanov It is obviously a socket input stream, and I assure you that its `available()` method can deliver a positive result. One thing it certainly *can't* be is a `java.io.InputStream`, because it's abstract.

Comment: I added some information at the bottom of the post to respond to some of these things.

Comment: Re your edit, all that means is that the instructor was also wrong to misuse `available()`. If you're not permitted to change it you cannot possibly solve this problem completely. Show him this page, and the Javadoc for [`ObjectInputStream.available()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available--), where it says nothing about a complete object being available.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening, but I'm not sure I understand why.

When I called reset() after sending, and then read the objects in at the receiving end, there was still 1 byte left in the stream. This is what was causing me to fall into the if-clause and then block when reading again (because there was really no object to read).

I had to call reset because I was sending a persistent object (the array). I noticed that I didn't have to call reset when I was only sending the string, and the difference between the string and the array was that the array was a data member of the class while the string was being created anew each time the loop ran.

So, I created a non-persistent copy of the array that I wanted to send, and sent that copy. When I did this, I didn't have to call reset (still don't understand why). Further, after reading from the input stream, there were 0 bytes left inside, so it never put the program in a position where readObject would block.

I think I kinda understand why I don't have to reset when sending non-persistent objects, but I don't understand why reset() was causing data to be left in the corresponding input stream.

Either way, it works as intended now.

Comment: I don't understand it either. `reset()` doesn't leave extra bytes in the stream. It does send something, but `ObjectInputStream` reads it all under the hood. Something else must have been doing that. Are you sure you aren't writing to the underlying stream somewhere? You could also investigate `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()`. In any case the underlying problem can still occur, as there is no guarantee an entire object will arrive at once.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. When I would send the persistent object and then reset(), available was returning 1. When I sent a non-persistent object, it returned 0. And yeah, I'm sure that I'm not writing to it anywhere else. There aren't that many lines of code to comb through, but still, just changing the usage of reset (and nothing else) fixes the problem, so that's probably proof that I'm not writing to it elsewhere.